# How to Update specific Column value in UWP sfGrid

Tags: c#, uwp, syncfusion

I want to update The value of a specific Column for the selected Row in UWP fGrid
Which EventArgs should I use?

```
 public void deleteUser()
    {
        var recordIndex = this._dtGrid.ResolveToRecordIndex(e.RowColumnIndex.RowIndex);
        var mappingName = this._dtGrid.Columns[0].MappingName;



        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(" UPDATE TO USER_INFO SET USE_YN='N' WHERE USER_ID='"+mappingName+"'");

        AppInstance.Ins.dbHelper.ExecuteTransaction(sb.ToString());

        _isDtChanged = true; 
    }
```

Delete button (Appbar)

```
  private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (_headerId)
        {
            
            case "userinform":
                {
                    UserinfoModel model = (DataGridFrame.Content as Userinfo.userinfo01).DataContext as UserinfoModel;
                    model.deleteRow(sender, e);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using 'SelectedItem'!

```
    public void DeleteRow()
    {           
        string del_id = (_dtGrid.SelectedItem as FunctionDataGridModel).id;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("UPDATE USER_INFO SET USE_YN ='N' WHERE USER_ID='"+del_id+"'");
        AppInstance.Ins.dbHelper.ExecuteScalar(sb.ToString());           
    }
```